# Convert percentage symbols to u+hex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I need to replace decoded string which has percentage symbols to U+hex.

String:

```
"text=%F0%9F%98%8A&id=60&tags=";
```

What I need:

change `%F0%9F%98%8A` to `'U+1F60A'` or `1F60A` (globally), according to http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html.

Comment: You want `"text=U+1F60A&id=60&tags="` as return? Or just `"text=&id=60&tags="`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `decodeURIComponent` will give you a perfectly good Unicode string. What are you planning to do with the string with `U+` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `1f60a`:

```
var c = decodeURIComponent("%F0%9F%98%8A").codePointAt(0).toString(16);
```

Note that `\u1f60a` wont work in JS (although it will as an HTML entity), you need 2 codepoints; `c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` & `c.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second paragraph? Won't `charCodeAt(1)` return undefined?

Comment: JS uses UTF16 and the emoji is in the range where it requires 2 characters to be represented: `"".length == 2`

Comment: Specifically: `"" == "\ud83d\ude0a" == true`

Comment: Alex, could you also help me to achieve "text=1f60a&id=60&tags=" after "text=%F0%9F%98%8A&id=60&tags=" ? Please bear in mind that I don't know for sure the exact number of codes I need to convert, and don't know their values. Also, before this percentage code and after it can exist other symbols, e. g. "text=asfa  af asf afaf%F0%9F%98%8Awtaaf asf asf &id=60&tags="

Comment: Or, I know how to implement it using regex and string splitting. Let me know if you know better implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var message = "This is my message %F0%9F%98%8A and I love emojis!";
$("p").text(decodeURI(message));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

var message